# How to remove constant background from an image?

Tags: image-processing

I'm not sure how to remove the paper background from this logo with v9.

[image]

This is really not the same as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/remove-image-background-of-headshot-in-mathematica), but I think similar methods  apply.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not as classy as @belisarius', but:

```
i1 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZfw.png"
ColorReplace[i1, RGBColor@PixelValue[i1, {2, 2}], .02]
```

[image: logo]

**Edit**:

Perhaps it would be better would be to use Vitaliy's method, illustrated in [this excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9449/61). In this version, the image has a white background, not transparent (hence the difference in color, I suppose):

```
data = ImageData[i1];
Image[data /. {x_, y_, z_} /; 
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, data[[2, 2]]] < .3 -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: logo2]

The value of .3 is taken from looking at a `ListPlot` of the `EuclideanDistance` values.

Comment: Hehe ... It's not a "classyness" problem. I don't have v9 :)

Answer (score 15):

It's actually easier than your linked question, since your ROI is monochromatic!

```
i1 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZfw.png"
i2 = Image[ImageData[
   ImageMultiply[Binarize[ColorSeparate[i1, "HSB"][[1]]], i1]] /. {0., 0., 0.} -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you want a fully saturated image, you could do something like

```
pmax = Position[ImageData[ColorSeparate[i1, "HSB"][[2]]], 1.][[1]]
Image@Replace[#, Except[{1., 1., 1.}] -> Extract[#, pmax], {2}] &@ ImageData[i2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice answer (although kind of brevity is the soul of wit ;) ). @M.R if you eventually want to turn the white background (what the verb "remove" implies; at least to me) to transparent please read this contribution of Szabolcs implementing a reverse blend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041703/remove-white-background-from-an-image-and-make-it-transparent

Answer (score 7):

In version 10 there is now a `RemoveBackground` function, with more options and parameters than you could dream of. Without any help, it will do this:

```
i1 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZfw.png";
RemoveBackground[i1]
```

[image: simple remove background]

but with some encouragement, in the form of a hint about the background's colour, or some marker positions to indicate the background, it can do even better:

```
RemoveBackground[i1, {"Background",  {RGBColor[0.9, 0.9, .7], .1}}]
```

[image: better remove background]