# How to make black text on white background

Tags: image-processing, image, text

I have a Georgian black text on "dirty yellow" paper

[image]

I want to make pdf, black text on white   paper .

I  try

[image]

I also try to like this...

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Comment: Try `Binarize` but it won't fix the fact that `"Georgian"` is not there.

Comment: Do you have Mathematica 10 or above? Try [`RemoveBackground[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html)

Comment: Possible duplicates [(18137)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/how-to-remove-constant-background-from-an-image/55207#55207), [(80742)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80742/removing-gutter-shadows-from-scanned-pages/95664#95664)

Comment: @blochwave I have a *Mathematica 10*, and RemoveBackground[] doeasn't work [see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xubxo6z06nbwww2/www.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: `TextRecognize` uses Tesseract. If you search on Google for "tesseract georgian" there are some search results which indicate that there are Georgian language files. Then of course one has to figure out where to put those language files. Might be easier to learn to use Tesseract on its own.