# How can I remove the background from a bokeh photo?

Tags: image-processing, image

Is there a way to remove the [bokeh background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) from photos using Mathematica? An example photo is given below.

[image: puppy]

I tried the methods that are answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/how-to-remove-constant-background-from-an-image) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/remove-image-background-of-headshot-in-mathematica), but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132844/280, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151332/280

Comment: `RemoveBackground[img, "Salient"]` works pretty well here as a quick background removal [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtfp.png)

Comment: @ydd oh it wasn't working in MMA 12 but now it works. Can you post this as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMAtq.jpg"]
```

Adding as an answer, here are two methods to remove the blurry background. There are likely several more methods.

### Using RemoveBackground

The `"Salient"` method works well without any further modification needed:

```
sal = RemoveBackground[img, "Salient"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Using ImageSaliencyFilter

This actually might produce the same results as RemoveBackground (other than the black instead of white background), but I'm not sure.

```
sfil = ImageSaliencyFilter[img];
sfil*img
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]