# How to make a smooth electronic signature?

Tags: image-processing

I have scanned a signature and that looks like this

[image: Scanned signature]

I want to smooth it. I saw [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/removing-graininess-from-a-handwritten-signature) where they do this using Photoshop or GIMP.

I tried to replicate that in Mathematica so I can automatize the process  since I have to run this on 50+ signatures.

What I did was

```
image = Import["path/to/my/image"];

ImageResize[Threshold[  GaussianFilter[ImageResize[image, Scaled[2]], 5], {"Hard", "Cluster"}], 400]
```

And got this

[image: Processed signature]

It looks smoother but also a little bit blurry. I think I got a better result with GIMP but it will take a lot of time if I do that by hand 50+ times.

This is what I got with GIMP

[image: GIMP result]

Any idea how to improve this?

==UPDATE==

I got something a little bit better

```
smooth[img_]:=Block[{data,nimg=ImageResize[Opening[Threshold[GaussianFilter[ImageResize[img,Scaled[2]],5],{"Hard","Cluster"}],DiskMatrix[2]],400]},data=ImageData[nimg];ImageAdd[nimg,Blur[ColorNegate@Erosion[DeleteSmallComponents[Dilation[ColorNegate@Binarize[Image[data/.{x_,y_,z_}/;EuclideanDistance[{x,y,z},data[[45,45]]]<0.05->{1,1,1}],.99],4]],3],5]]]
```

This gives me

[image: Better result]

Part of this came from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/remove-image-background-of-headshot-in-mathematica).

Comment: Please include the "desired" (GIMP) result image

Comment: Just in case [GIMP has a batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

Comment: Added GIMP result. I'll take a look at GIMP batch mode but would like to do it with Mathematica too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't achieve exactly the same effect in Mathematica as you will with GIMP, but I think this is pretty close:

```
ColorConvert[
 ImageAdjust[
  MeanShiftFilter[ImageAdjust[ImageAdjust[image, {0, 0, 2}]], 
   5, .1], {1, 0}], "Grayscale"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sweet! I'll take this as a reference and try to improve it. Thanks so much!