# Nontrivial background removal

Tags: image-processing, image, computer-vision

I have an image of a product on a poorly made green screen and need to segment out just the product:

[image]

The problem is that it contains a mirror, so simple color-based methods are not enough.

I tried playing with the function RemoveBackground using markers, but no luck. Here's what I tried so far:

```
RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", Green}]
RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", {"Uniform", 0.1}}]
```

[image]
[image]

**Update:**

With python and opencv can do it easily using the Grabcut algorithm referenced in the comments, but I can't find the way to do it with MMA.

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread(path_to_img)
print "img", img.shape

# resize
side = 600
ratio = float(side) / max(img.shape)
img = skimage.img_as_ubyte(
    skimage.transform.resize(
        img, (int(img.shape[0] * ratio), int(img.shape[1] * ratio))))

s = (img.shape[0] / 10, img.shape[1] / 10)
rect = (s[0], s[1], img.shape[0] - 2 * s[0], img.shape[1] - 2 * s[1])

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You may try something like colors = DominantColors@i; RemoveBackground[i, {"Background", {colors[[1]], 0.05}}]

Comment: Also related ... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/remove-image-background-of-headshot-in-mathematica/9450#9450

Comment: @s.s.o that doesn't help with the problem of the mirror...

Comment: Does mathematica have the grabcut algorithm implemented?  I could do this with opencv pretty easy: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html

Comment: Almost: `mask = FillingTransform@
    DeleteBorderComponents@
     DeleteSmallComponents@ColorNegate@ContourDetect[#, 0.4] &@
  ImageAdjust@img` and `ImageMultiply[mask, img]`. If only I could enclose the region of interest in `mask` :(

Comment: You can improve this by using taking your mask, then make a background marker `back2 = MorphologicalPerimeter@
  Dilation[Closing[mask, DiskMatrix[20]], DiskMatrix[15]]`.  Feed this into GrowCutComponents: `c = GrowCutComponents[i, {mask, back2}];`.  The result is pretty good: `SetAlphaChannel[Image[c - 1], i]`

Comment: @M.R. there is a Java opencv grabcut implementation which you can link to trivially using the ideas proposed by Leonid Shifrin [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376). Essentially, why write your own implementation when you could reuse an old one?

Comment: Is this something you're wanting to apply programmatically to a large collection of images, or just a few images?

Comment: I notice this question still doesn't have an accepted answer - is there some aspect you were looking for that isn't covered here?

Comment: @corey979 Well,actually I don't know that since OP have no any response. :)

Comment: Have you seen [`GrowCutComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GrowCutComponents.html)? It seems similar to GrabCut.

Comment: SetAlphaChannel[image, 
 FillingTransform@Dilation[EdgeDetect[image], 1]]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## 1.This method is from documentation of function `ClusterClassify`

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5xF.jpg"];
imageData = Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[image, "LAB"]], 1];
c = ClusterClassify[imageData, 4, Method -> "KMedoids"];
decision = c[imageData];
mask = Image /@ 
  ComponentMeasurements[{image, 
     Partition[decision, First@ImageDimensions[image]]}, "Mask"][[All,
     2]]
```

[image]

```
allMask = FillingTransform[Dilation[ColorNegate[mask[[4]]], 1]];
SetAlphaChannel[image, Blur[allMask, 8]]
```

[image]

## 2.Based on machine learning

#### Method one,Classify the pixel by chain a nerve

I have to say this is worthless method in real life,because it is **very very very** low efficiency(Maybe when you have a *CUDA* feature GPU, it will be more faster).I don't remember how long I have run it.Well,Just for fun.

First we select a range that you need,which just is a  selection
   roughly that mean you can include some singular point in your trained
   data.Of course you can make yourself trained data.This is what I
   select that arbitrarily

[image]

Then define a net and train it

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5xF.jpg"];
trainData = Join[Thread[Rule[no, False]], Thread[Rule[yes, True]]];
net = NetChain[{20, Tanh, 2, 
    SoftmaxLayer["Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {True, False}}]]}, 
   "Input" -> 3];
ringQ = NetTrain[net, trainData, MaxTrainingRounds -> 20]
```

[image]

Be patient and wait some minutes,then you can get your ring.The final
   effect is depened on your training data and some luck.

```
Image[Map[If[ringQ[#],#,N@{1,1,1}]&,ImageData[image],{2}]]
```

[image]

We can use my above method to refine it in following step.

#### Method two,use the built-in function of `Classify`

This method is not bad as the result effect,but actually I will not tell you this code cost my one night to run,which mean this method is slower than that `NetChain`.
Firstly,make some sample data

[image]

```
match = Classify[<|False -> Catenate[ImageData[no]], 
    True -> Catenate[ImageData[yes]]|>];
ImageApply[If[match[#], #, {1, 1, 1}] &, image]
```

Be more patient please,after just one night,the result will show you.like this:
[image]

## 3.Above answer for another motivation or just fun,but in this part,I will post some method for `image-processing`

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5xF.jpg"];
```

#### Method one

```
SetAlphaChannel[image, 
 Erosion[Blur[
   DeleteSmallComponents[
    FillingTransform[Binarize[GradientFilter[image, 1], 0.035]]], 10],
   1]]
```

[image]

#### Method two

```
SetAlphaChannel[image, 
 Blur[Binarize[
   Image[WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[image, 2], 
      Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 0.2}] - 1]], 5]]
```

[image]

#### Method three

```
SetAlphaChannel[image, 
 Blur[FillingTransform[
   MorphologicalBinarize[
    ColorNegate[
     First[ColorSeparate[ColorConvert[image, "CMYK"]]]], {.6, .93}]], 
  7]]
```

[image]

#### Last but not least,this method do some principal component decomposition of color channels,which can face more situation commonly

```
First[KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[
  ColorCombine /@ Tuples[ColorSeparate[image], {3}]]]
```

[image]

Note that picture from 2 to 5,every picture have more strong contrast then origin.Than we can use fist three method do next step.

Comment: our are missing a HUGE chuck of the mirror.

Comment: Great answer. Methods 1 and 3 seem to work fine.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method that could be iterated and refined to replicate the opencv result, I think.

First we use the `ClusterClassify` [method of yobe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132844/nontrivial-background-removal/133000#133000) then we simply fill in the holes by generating a mask that gets the frame we need and combine this into a single mask.

First the boiler plate:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5xF.jpg"];

clusterGet[image_] :=
  Module[{imageData, c, decision},
   imageData = Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[image, "LAB"]], 1]; 
   c = ClusterClassify[imageData, 4, Method -> "KMedoids"]; 
   decision = c[imageData]; 
   Image /@ 
    ComponentMeasurements[{image, 
       Partition[decision, First@ImageDimensions[img]]}, "Mask"][[All,
       2]]
   ];

maskCombine[{base_, others__}] :=

  Block[{root = base, 
    alphas = SetAlphaChannel[#, ColorNegate@#] & /@ {others}},
   Do[root = ImageCompose[base, a], {a, alphas}];
   root
   ];
```

then figure out which mask we want:

```
baseMask = clusterGet[img][[4]]
```

[image: base mask]

then we need to create a filling mask for that:

```
fillingMask = Closing[
   EdgeDetect@
    MeanShiftFilter[ImageAdjust[Lighter@img, 2], 1, .01, 
     MaxIterations -> 5],
   4.5];
```

[image: filling mask]

then set the composite mask as the overal image:

```
SetAlphaChannel[img,
 ColorNegate@maskCombine@{baseMask, fillingMask}]
```

[image: composite]

Using more sophisticated filters I've been able to build a better filling mask that minimizes the amount of lost green space/frame but I can't remember exactly which set of filters I combined. For those looking to extend this, the edge-preserving filters such as `PeronaMalikFilter` appear to be the place to start. There are [tons of filters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageFilteringAndNeighborhoodProcessing.html) to apply, so I'm sure trial and error can give you the results you want.

You could also use Java and opencv, doing more or less what Leonid Shifrin does [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376) or write your own simple boundary detection code. I did some of the latter, but it's generally just too slow to be properly workable and figuring out the appropriate pixel distance function is, again, a matter of trial and error.

Comment: This result is great, but may be it can be further improved by some `DeleteSmallComponents` or come edge refining?

Comment: Funny,I solve the problem,then you get the bounty. :)

Comment: @yobe I have literally no idea why, honestly.

Comment: @yode I was on vacation, so sorry, I don't know how why you didn't get the bounty

Answer (score 3):

With [helpful ideas of KAI](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132844/nontrivial-background-removal#comment358646_132844):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5xF.jpg"]

mask = FillingTransform@
    DeleteBorderComponents@
     DeleteSmallComponents@
      ColorNegate@
       ContourDetect[#, 0.4]&@
        ImageAdjust @ img

back = MorphologicalPerimeter@
        Dilation[Closing[mask, DiskMatrix[15]], DiskMatrix[2]]

c = Binarize @ Colorize @ GrowCutComponents[img, {mask, back}]

ImageMultiply[img, c] // RemoveBackground // ImageCrop
```

[image]

Not a complete solution, but maybe could serve as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks but I really need it to be a complete object without any missing parts - just like how python does it.

Comment: @M.R. virtually all of the functions have options (e.g. check out the `Method` options of `Binarize` for example). So does `DeleteSmallComponents`. Why not try those yourself?

Comment: @blochwave I was hoping the underlying algorithm choice for grabcut would be accessible