# Improve scanned image with handwritten text for high-contrast printing: how it can be done with Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

I have a set of scanned documents with handwritten text which by default is printed with very low contrast. Here is an example (a part of a document):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgRUc.jpg"]
```

> [image]

The entire text is written in one pen. But when printing directly to a black&white laser printer with a grayscale conversion, I get a hardly readable result. I tried to improve the printing quality using `ColorReplace`, but it introduces artifacts:

```
{img2 = ImageTake[img, {158, 510}, {677, 1105}], 
 ColorReplace[img2, RGBColor[{169, 147, 209}/255.] -> Black, .15]}
```

> [image: output]

Is there a better way to improve the quality of handwritten text without introducing artifacts?

Thinking: given that the problem is very common, maybe there are ready-made neural networks for this purpose?

Comment: Perhaps a combination of contrast correction, speckle removal and smoothing? ``Binarize[Blur[ColorNegate@DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize[ImageAdjust[img, .2], .99], 100], 3], .8]`` You can play with the parameters to achieve a more desirable result ...

Comment: @Domen The result isn't satisfactory, and I expect that the whole approach based on simple `Binarize` cann't give a good result. I would expect that a solution going through a LAB colorspace for separating the handwritten text would give something better. Also, I think there should be a neural net based approach for this purpose (since the problem is very common).

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrM6.png) is the result I get with my approach. Which features of the result do you still consider to be unsatisfactory? I can't read cyrillic, but compared to the original images (and to your approach), the result is much better.

Comment: @Domen The result contains large gaps inside of
 the letters of the handwritten text. This is expected when using a Binarize-based approach. Actually, these gaps are absent in the original image: they just correspond to lesser-saturated color of the pen.

Comment: A great follow up question is why TextRecognize remains so bad after all these years…?

Comment: Related: "[Nontrivial background removal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132844/280)."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### First attempt with acceptable result

Here is an approach which gives a satisfactory result. `ColorsNear` by default uses the `"CIE2000"` `ColorDistance` metric which works well in this case. The obtained image is readable and doesn't have too many artifacts. However, the result critically depends on a good choice for the `penColor` value, and requires manual adjusting the `distance` parameter.

```
penColor = {169, 147, 209}/255.;
(* This value is found by trial and error *)
distance = .16;
img2 = ColorDetect[img, ColorsNear[RGBColor[penColor], distance]]
mask = MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate[ImageApply[Min[#/penColor] &, img]]]
final = img*ColorNegate[img2] - mask
```

> [image: img2]

> [image: mask]

> [image: final]

The inscription looks contrasting and, which is very important, at the same time naturally continuous, the noise level is acceptable.

---

### Improved approach based on `DominantColors`

Here is an attempt to improve the algorithm.

The main disadvantage of the previous approach is that it cruicially depends on manually choosen value for the pen color. Let's employ `DominantColors` for finding this value automatically:

```
dc = DominantColors[img, 3]
```

> [image: dominant colors]

The first color is background, the second is print color and the third is writing color.

Second, we can directly isolate the writing, the print and the background with `ColorDetect`. The `"CIE76"` `ColorDistance` metric in this case allows to achieve the same results as the `"CIE2000"`, but is much faster:

```
(* This value is found by trial and error *)
dist = .219;
{back, print, writing} = ColorDetect[img, ColorsNear[#, dist, "CIE76"]] & /@ dc;
```

Surprisingly, some places where the writing overlaps itself and becomes most saturated are not recognized by `ColorDetect` as part of the writing, but fortunately are not recognized as part of the background either (same problem with the `"CIE2000"` metric):

```
ImageTake[#, {697, 754}, {923, 951}] & /@ {img, writing, back}
```

> [image: list]

Due to this feature we should use `back` at the final stage for filling such holes in the writing as follows:

```
final = ColorNegate[writing + print + ColorNegate[back]]
```

> [image: final]

The result is very similar to what we got with the previous method. The significant advantage of this approach is that it has only one parameter, which must be adjusted by trial and error.

However, the result can be improved further by clipping the grayscale values from the top:

```
Manipulate[ImageClip[
  ImageTake[final, {215, 520}, {850, 1232}], {0, thr2}, {0, 1}], 
   {{thr2, .82}, .9, .6, -.01}]
```

> [image: animation]

The value `thr2 = .82` seems optimal:

```
final2 = ImageClip[final, {0, .82}, {0, 1}]
```

[image: final2]

Answer (score 13):

## High contrast by `"PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"`

I use [`DimensionReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduce.html)`[data,n]`
which projects the data into another space of dimension `n`.
The base of that space is defined by `Method -> "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"`, orthogonal vectors that best fit the data.

I use [`Blur[img,5]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blur.html) to smooth the data, and noisy data is harder to classify. One could play with [`Dilation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html),
[`FillingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingTransform.html) and other transformations that fill space between data.

Because I'm choosing a space of dimension 3, the partitioned data is interpreted by [`Image`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) as an RGB image.

The main component is assigned red, and the second component is green. The order is not necessarily consistent.

Because writing, print and background are predominantly similar colours, each of these should be given a primary colour. However, the print is black, which is a zero magnitude for any vector base, so it didn't get its own vector.

```
img  = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgRUc.jpg"]
img2 = Image@Partition[DimensionReduce[
    Flatten[ImageData[Blur[img,5]],1]
    , 3
    , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
    , Method -> "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"
    
],3974]
```

[image]

Comment: I get [a different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TboOc.png) with your code

Comment: Could you provide some clarification on what `Method -> "PrincipalComponentsAnalysis"` actually produces? It's not clear why we have so many colors in the final image.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've added another answer with new findings regarding the `DimensionReduce` approach.

Comment: Could you please show how to properly get the desired grayscale image from the output of `DimensionReduce`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov there is no point. The contrast here is generated by the orthogonal colours, any advantage will be lost if we project it to grayscale.

Comment: Then this method is not suitable, since the end goal is to print the scanned image on a laser printer, as stated in the question.

Comment: Sure, this answer should not be accepted. I still think it has value. You are welcome to downvote the answer if you think it doesn't.

Comment: It certainly has value and I already upvoted it. I still think that there should be a way to get a proper grayscale image from the output of `DimensionReduce`, but I feel like it will end up being more complicated and less reliable than the approach I posted in my [first answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271347/280).

Answer (score 6):

When thinking on the `DimensionReduce` approach [suggested by rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271343/280) I realized that it would probably be better to work in a [linear colorspace](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/280) when performing dimension reduction, and also that we can directly request reduction to dimension 1 (what is formally our goal, since we are going to produce a grayscale image as a result). Then I looked at the obtained distribution of intensity values:

```
data = Rescale@Flatten@DimensionReduce[Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "XYZ"]], 1], 1];
Histogram[Flatten[data], Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> {All, {0, .01}}]
```

> [image: histogram]

From the histogram it is clear that we have a sum of three distributions with vastly different scales. Playing with clipping thresholds allows to produce quite interesting results which I still don't fully understand:

```
lowerThr = .16;
upperThr = .19;
dataClipped = Clip[data, {lowerThr, upperThr}, {0, 1}];
ColorNegate@Image@ArrayReshape[dataClipped, Reverse@ImageDimensions[img]]
```

> [image: final]

The image obtained contains more artifacts, than I got with the [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271347/280) method. However, I suspect that this approach can be improved for providing even better results.

Answer (score 2):

Fully automatic quick and dirty approach:

```
background = First@DominantColors[img, ColorCoverage -> {.6, 1}];
cd = ColorDetect[img, ColorsNear[background, 0, "CIE76"]]
```

> [image: out]

```
final = HistogramTransform[img, cd]
```

> [image: out]

The amount of noise is high, but contrast and readability have increased dramatically.